# Configuring Clean LibGDX Project with Kotlin Sync Failed invalid type code:82

Tags: gradle, kotlin, libgdx

I am trying to configure clean libgdx project with kotlin.First i generated a clean project with libgdxs tool then even though i did everything in official documentation i am having sync failed 
Cause: invalid type code: 82

I did everything written here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libGDX-with-Kotlin
Main project directory build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.11'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"



    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "my-gdx-game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.9'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.5'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"


    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion"



    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

desktop folder build.gradle i only changed apply plugin java to apply plugin kotlin
core folder build.gradle i only changed apply plugin java to apply plugin kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add 
**sourceCompatibility = 1.8

targetCompatibility = 1.8**
In your build.gradle check it once

```
  project(":core") {
            apply plugin: "kotlin"


            dependencies {
                sourceCompatibility = 1.8
                targetCompatibility = 1.8

                compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
                compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
                compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
                compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion"



            }
}
```

Comment: added that still same